# observe someone ... to have been...，

Tags: syntactic-analysis

My question is in following sentence

> What happens, says Hume, is that we observe individuals of one species to have been constantly attended by individuals of another.

Why use **to have been** instead of **have been**?

I searched for this and only get 5 patterns,

1、observe someone/something

2、observe someone/something do something

3、observe someone/something doing something

4、observe that…

5、be observed to do something

I don't see there is observe someone/something to do something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to understand with the present infinitive:

> We observe individuals of one species to be constantly attended by
>   individuals of another.

That could not possibly be:

> *We observe individuals of one species be constantly attended by
>   individuals of another.

A non-finite verb form is required after a construction  such as *we observe* + noun phrase. It would also be possible to write, with a slightly different emphasis:

> We observe individuals of one species being constantly attended by
>   individuals of another.

But *being*, just like *to be* is also non-finite.

Comment: Isn't _observe_ normally followed by an NP + **bare infinitive** instead of a **to-infinitive**? For example, _The police observed a man enter the bank._

Comment: That is certainly possible, but I think _The police observed a man to be entering the bank_ might be just about possible. My answer needs to be read in the context of the question. We can't cover everythng.

Comment: I understand that you can't cover everything. But OP says he's searched for the complementation patterns for the word _observe_ but he can't find the pattern "observe + NP + to-infinitive" (I can't find this pattern in any dictionaries either). Isn't it considered incorrect to say _The police observed a man to enter the bank_? But, according to your answer, it is acceptable to write _We observe individuals of one species to be constantly attended_ (to-infinitive), but not _be constantly attended_ (bare infinitive). So I wonder why that is so.

Comment: I've answered the question to the OP's apparent satisfaction. If you have another question, you might like to post it separately.

Answer (score -1):

It is the past infinitive of the verb 'to be'. In other verbs as: 'I have known them to have walked from London to Manchester in two days' or 'There have been occasions when I have witnessed him to have eaten nothing but jelly babies all day'. It is a bit formal other than with 'to be', but grammatically correct, none the less.